# Having Problems updating Linked List

Tags: c++

```
class MostBought {        //class in a .h file
private:
    typedef struct node {
        double moneySpent;
        char Name[50];
        node *next;
} * nodePtr3;

nodePtr3 head3;
nodePtr3 curr3;
nodePtr3 temp3;
nodePtr3 next3;

public:
    MostBought();
    void addMoney(double x, char Category[50]);
    void PrintList(); 
}; 

MostBought::MostBought() {  //everything else in main.cpp
    head3 = NULL;
    curr3 = NULL;
    temp3 = NULL;
    next3 = NULL;
}


void MostBought::addMoney(double x, char Category[50]) {
temp3 = head3;
while (temp3 != NULL) {
    if (temp3->Name == Category) {
        temp3->moneySpent = temp3->moneySpent + x;
    }
    else {
        temp3 = temp3->next;
    }
}
}
```

Am calling addMoney in main() like this
"addMoney(aa.Price, aa.Category)" where aa an object of a struct.
Programm compiles, but when i try to print all the nodes with their names and values, all values are equal to 0.
Any ideas what is going wrong?

Comment: How are we supposed to know if its correct? We see only these lines and can't build them.

Comment: Also, a word of advice: use English for the nouns and verbs of your program (variables and functions). It makes it easier to share code, and to get help from abroad...

Comment: Am asking if i have done any syntax error or something like that.

Comment: Yeh you are correct, let me edit it.

Comment: If you have a syntax error, then your compiler will tell you.

Comment: If `Name` is not `std::string` then `temp3->Name == Category` compares pointers, not the strings. Also note that in a function parameter, `char[50]` is 100% equivalent to just `char*`.

Comment: @tuple_cat yeh i meant to compare the strings, lemmie try that out.

Comment: You should just change to `std::string` to see if your linked list actually works.  Then when it works, change back to the char arrays if you have to and work out those issues.

Comment: Recommendation: Separate the linked list from the data being linked. That way you can easily test the linked list for validity without the other logic getting in the way.

Comment: i flaged this for a mod to delete it and remade the question. Well i cant, its all part of a project and it has to be done in this way.

Answer (score 1):

Line 4 with the '(temp3->Onoma == Katigoria)' test does not give a syntax error but likely does not do what you expect it to do. It does not do a string  compare, it compares if two memory addresses are the same. If you want to see if two strings are equal, use a strcmp() or similar function.

Comment: So how am i supposed to use strcmp(), if Name and Category are pointers?

Comment: @supItsMe, `strcmp` is well documented. I recommend you start at [`<cstring>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstring)

Comment: using strcmp just freezes the whole program for some reason

Comment: @supItsMe Probably the strings are not null-terminated.